# The border of the System

Tags: general-relativity

In General Relativity, if the system accelerates, the inside of the system and the outside of the system will have different speed of time.

Where is the boundary of the system?

If a human accelerates closer to the speed of light, does that mean the human exist inside of their specific system?

Comment: Can you please try to improve the sentence structure of your question a little bit? It is very hard to read right now...

Comment: ok, how about this ?

Comment: I still find it impossible to understand what you're asking...

Comment: It seems it has been edited .

Comment: Fwiw I find it clear enough. (No time to answer though.)